# Template.myTemplate.onRendered not working on multiple templates

Tags: function, templates, meteor

I've got a registration process which has multiple steps.

I've got a progress bar that rises by 25% between each step

Each step is on a separate route e.g. (/register -> /choose-email -> /choose-alerts) etc.

To add an animation to the progress bar between each step I created the following function:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.chooseEmail.onRendered(function () {
      var bar = this.find("#progressBar");
      bar.style.width = "25%";
    });

    Template.chooseAlerts.onRendered(function () {
      var bar = this.find("#progressBar");
      bar.style.width = "50%";
    });
}
```

For some reason however, the second onRendered function will not work. When I load the first template "chooseEmail", I see the progress bar animate form 0-25%. When I load the second template "chooseAlerts" the progress bar is at 50% the second it appears on the screen. So the onRendered isn't working

Template chooseEmail

```
<template name="chooseEmail">

    {{> navbar}}
    <div class="container chooseEmail">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h1>Choose where your alerts go</h1>
                <h2>This is the email address we will send all your alerts to.</h2>
                <h6>You can change this later.</h6>
            </div>

            <div class="progress">
                <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped active"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="well">

                <div class="row">


                    <form name="chooseEmail" id="chooseEmail" method="post" role="form">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="alertEmail" autofocus required name="alertEmail" placeholder="Email Address" value="{{userEmail}}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <button type="submit" data-loading-text="Roger that!" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Ok, next step!</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>


                </div><!-- Row -->
            </div><!-- Well -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Template chooseAlerts

```
<template name="chooseAlerts">
    {{> navbar}}
    <div class="container chooseAlerts">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h1>Setup some alerts</h1>
                <h2>These are the events that will Hooked will notify you about</h2>
                <h6>You can change these later.</h6>
            </div>

            <div class="progress">
                <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped active"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="well">

                <!--Choose Alerts-->

                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
                                <label for="checkbox1">
                                    Check me out
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
                                <label for="checkbox1">
                                    Check me out
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
                                <label for="checkbox1">
                                    Check me out
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- End Col -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
                                <label for="checkbox1">
                                    Check me out
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
                                <label for="checkbox1">
                                    Check me out
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
                                <label for="checkbox1">
                                    Check me out
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- End Col -->
                    </div><!-- End Row -->

                </form>



            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

For some reason however, the second onRendered function will not work. I can't work out why, or work out if there is any alternative way to adjust the width of the progress bar upon page load

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you mind pasting the code for both of your templates?

Comment: Sure, edited it to add templates. Thanks